# Firebase CLI is not authenticating because Google account is not retaining authorization

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I just downloaded the Firebase CLI (through `firebase-tools` NPM module) and I'm trying to `firebase login`. Each time I'm redirected to my browser where I give the Firebase CLI app permissions to my account and I keep getting a screen saying "Firebase CLI Login Failed":

[image: Firebase CLI Login Failed]

I've tried running `firebase login --no-localhost` and that also doesn't seem to work.

[image: Firebase --no-localhost command line]

When I look at my Google Account OAuth authorizations (https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), Firebase is not listed. It's as if Google isn't saving my option to allow the Firebase CLI app when I click "Allow" on this screen.

[image]

I've tried this on two different Internet connections with two different Google accounts (one Gmail and on G Suite) and the results are the same. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more troubleshooting and research I found that Firebase CLI will not authenticate or deploy properly if your computer is behind a proxy. This is a [known issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/155). I had a program installed on my computer that monitors all my Internet traffic and it does so using a proxy. Once I uninstalled that program, Firebase CLI was able to authenticate and deploy without an issue.

Comment: Any solutions for those of us in china where google services are blocked and can't do without VPN?